# Receive data in MVC controller from webrole

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, azure, azure-web-roles

I understood how to communicate between Web, Worker role and the flow in MVC architecture.

My question is, after I query the data from a table in web role, how can the controller in MVC get this data to diplay in the view?

I tried using a global static variable in webrole, where the data gets populated, but when I access the static variable from the controller, it only returned 'null'. Why am I getting a null?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, in case you use the storage client, the implementation would be like:

1. Create your Model:

   ```
       public class MyEntity : Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TableServiceEntity
       {
           public MyEntity()
           {
               PartitionKey = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MMddyyyy");
   ```

   ```
           RowKey = string.Format("{0:10}_{1}",
               DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.Now.Ticks, Guid.NewGuid());
       }

       // Define the properties.
       public string Title { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   }

2. Define your context class:

```
     public class MyDataContext : TableServiceContext
        {
            public MyDataContext(string baseAddress,
                StorageCredentials credentials)
                : base(baseAddress, credentials)
            { }

            public IQueryable GetMyEntity
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.CreateQuery("MyTableName");
                }
            }
        }
```

1. Implement your controller action method:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var context = new MyDataContext(storageAccount.TableEndpoint.AbsoluteUri, storageAccount.Credentials);

        var results = from g in context.GetMyEntity
                              where g.PartitionKey ==
                              DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("MMddyyyy")
                              select g;

        return View(results.FirstOrDefault());
    }
```

this is reference code only, which is very ugly and will hardly work as it is, but it still provides an example of how you can query the table storage in your MVC project.

Comment: Hi, the data reading part is done in Webrole for my appication in Run() function. If I implement the data reading part in controller of ASP.net MVC, what will the webrole be doing? My second question is, I have to query the table every 10 seconds to get the latest data. how to do this from controller? Thanks

Comment: Hi, I am not quite sure what you mean by Run() function. The Web Role is a kind of a hosting environment for your web application. You can think of hosting your Web App in a Web Role as deploying your Web App into the IIS of a Virtual Machine. Microsoft is doing the hosting part for you. So your Web App is running inside the Web Role and that is what the Web role is doing. to your second question: you could for example implement a JavaScript function in your View and call your controller asynchronously every 10 secs.

Answer (score 0):

are we talking about an application whose MVC part is hosted in a worker role and which gets data from a web role which is querying the table storage? Or are we talking about a ASP.NET MVC application here which is hosted in a web role?

static variables is not a good idea at all because of concurrency issues.

in case of scenario 1, how do you communicate with a web role? via web service call directly?

you cold simply call the service from your controller or delegate the call to another layer and then put this data in your model which is then displayed by the corresponding view.

have you tried debugging this application locally using the [azure local dev env][1]

[1]: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/morebits/archive/2010/12/01/using-windows-azure-development-environment-essentials.aspx ? or do you use the real azure infrastructure? Are you sure you are getting the data from your query? maybe the query is wrong? have you observed any exceptions?

we need more information here to be able to help you

Comment: I am implementing second scenario, The ASP.net MVC part is hosted in Web Role. The webrole queries the data from table storage. I checked it in debug and Yes I am able to query and get the correct data.